# Excel VBA changing color for CommandButton

Tags: vba, excel, commandbutton

I'm having problem with changing colors of my `CommandButton`. In the spreadsheet I add design button as form or ActiveX.

Then in VBA I try:

```
Activesheet.shapes("CommandButton1").visible = false
```

This one works just fine.

But then I try:

```
Activesheet.shapes.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(220, 105, 0)
```

It runs without error but nothing changes; color remains as it was before.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: `Shapes` is a collection, you need to specify which index you're working with. Also, forms and activex controls are wildly different, and don't work the same at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just try it like this:

```
ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(220, 105, 0)
```

Comment: Ye it works after i add Activesheet.CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(220, 105, 0). I should have tried it before. Thanks